How to make cli::cli_abort() evaluate dynamic arguments
How might I evaluate msg in this context?
f <- function(msg){
  cli::cli_abort("{msg} xxx")
}

f(msg = "{.var x}")
# Error in `f()`:
# ! {.var x} xxx
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


This isn’t really related to cli_abort(), the issue is that you want to evaluate a glue string twice.

I'd glue first:
> f <- function(msg){
+     cli::cli_abort(glue::glue("{msg} xxx"))
+ }
> f(msg = "{.var x}")
Error in `f()`:
! `x` xxx
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> 

